# Change colour on b-table detailed view

Tags: vue.js, bulma, buefy

I would like to be able to change the background colour of the details-window that the table supplies me. Right now I want to have another table inside the details-view, but that does look terrible right now due to mismatching colours.

**Example image:**
[image: a Example]

I have tried to read the documentation for both Bulma and Buefy but I can't seem to find if there actually is an option to change the background colour.

**Documentation:**

https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/table/

https://buefy.org/documentation/table/

Am I being completely blind here? Could anyone show me an example of how to change the colour?

Comment: Can you supply a CodePen or JSFiddle that reproduces this issue?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h4536fk0/6/

The "details" button is not displaying for some reason but it is to the left of the table row.

Comment: You want to change the background of the entire table, right? Have you tried using CSS?

Comment: Your JSFiddle is extremely confusing. Can you clean it up so it is closer to your question.. Help us help you........

Answer (score 0):

You can get around it by styling the element manually, but you have to style one of their "internal" elements (as opposed to the `b-table` component). I would call that a bug. Open an issue on their GitHub page.

```js
const data = [{"id": 1,"user": {"first_name": "Jesse","last_name": "Simmons"},"date": "2016/10/15 13:43:27","gender": "Male"}];


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      data,
      defaultOpenedDetails: [1]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle(row) {
      this.$refs.table.toggleDetails(row)
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.inner-table .table { background: gold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/buefy.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/2.0.46/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/buefy.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div id="app" class="container">

  <b-table :data="data" :opened-detailed="defaultOpenedDetails" detailed detail-key="id" :show-detail-icon="true">

    <template slot-scope="props">
      <b-table-column field="id" label="ID" width="40" numeric>{{ props.row.id }}</b-table-column>
      <b-table-column field="user.first_name" label="First Name">{{ props.row.user.first_name }}</b-table-column>
      <b-table-column field="user.last_name" label="Last Name">{{ props.row.user.last_name }}</b-table-column>
    </template>

    <template slot="detail" slot-scope="props">
      <b-table :data="data" class="inner-table">
        <template slot-scope="props">
          <b-table-column field="id" label="ID" width="40" numeric>{{ props.row.id }}</b-table-column>
          <b-table-column field="user.first_name" label="First Name">{{ props.row.user.first_name }}</b-table-column>
          <b-table-column field="user.last_name" label="Last Name">{{ props.row.user.last_name }}</b-table-column>
        </template>

        <template slot="detail" slot-scope="props">
          FOO
        </template>
      </b-table>
    </template>
  </b-table>
</div>
```

(based on https://buefy.org/documentation/table/ CodePen link for "Detailed row")